# Filter values in a dictionary of sets

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I would like to filter dictionary elements by the values in a list:

```
s_list = ['blue','white']
dict_set = {'A':{'red','orange','blue','white'},'B':set(),'C':{'white','green','yellow','blue'},'D':set(),'E':set()}
```

the output for dict_set would be:

```
dict_set = {'A':{'blue','white'},'B':set(),"C":{'white','blue'},'D':set(),'E':set()}}
```

(Empty sets can be left there, only filter sets that have values)

The implementation I tried to do results in empty sets:

```
for a,b in dict_set.items():
  dict_set[a] = set([x for x in a if b in s_list])
```

Comment: I your loop, `b` is always a set, and thus will never be in `s_list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a set out of your list and take the intersection with the values in the dict:

```
s_list = ['blue','white']
dict_set = {'A':{'red','orange','blue','white'},'B':set(),'C':{'white','green','yellow','blue'},'D':set(),'E':set()}

set_list = set(s_list)

{k:v & set_list for k, v in dict_set.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'blue', 'white'},
 'B': set(),
 'C': {'blue', 'white'},
 'D': set(),
 'E': set()}
```

If you don't want the empties, you can filter those with something like:

```
{k:v & set_list for k, v in dict_set.items() if v & set_list}
# {'A': {'blue', 'white'}, 'C': {'blue', 'white'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this would be:

```
s_list = ['blue','white']
dict_set = {'A':{'red','orange','blue','white'},'B':set(),'C':{'white','green','yellow','blue'},'D':set(),'E':set()}

# Now the fitering
dict_set = {j: {i for i in k if i in s_list} for j, k in dict_set.items()}
```

Comment: hmmm. yesterday I tested @Mark Meyer's, and my variant and it indicated that my variant would be faster

Comment: If my version is really the slowest, I am going to delete the statement

Comment: Do you still have the code you used for that testing?

Comment: No, that is the Problem

Answer (score 1):

No need to touch the keys or build new dictionary / sets. The sets offer updates:

```
for s in dict_set.values():
    s.intersection_update(s_list)
```

Or if you make `s_list` a `set`:

```
for s in dict_set.values():
    s &= s_set
```

**Benchmarks:**

Runtimes for doing it 100,000 times:

```
0.20 seconds mine
0.46 seconds @Kumpelinus's
0.21 seconds @MarkMeyer's
```

With `s_list` as a `set` (and my `set` version and removing the conversion in Mark's solution):

```
0.13 seconds mine
0.64 seconds @Kumpelinus's
0.18 seconds @MarkMeyer's
```

My benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat

def f1(dict_set, s_list):
    for s in dict_set.values():
        # s.intersection_update(s_list)
        s &= s_list

def f2(dict_set, s_list):
    for a,b in dict_set.items():
        dict_set[a] = set([x for x in a if b in s_list])

def f3(dict_set, s_list):
    # s_list = set(s_list)
    dict_set = {k:v & s_list for k, v in dict_set.items()}

n = 100000
for _ in range(3):
    for f in f1, f2, f3:
        s_list = ['blue','white']
        s_list = set(s_list)
        data = iter([{'A': {'red','orange','blue','white'},
                      'B': set(),
                      'C': {'white','green','yellow','blue'},
                      'D': set(),
                      'E': set()}
                     for _ in range(5 * n)])
        print(f.__name__, min(repeat(lambda: f(next(data), s_list), number=n)))
    print()
```